# How should Ajax routes in MVC be setup?

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

Should MVC Ajax requests be mapped the same way as regular requests in a MVC framework?

For example: Say I want to check and see if a username is available via ajax and have a method on a controller that performs this scope of work. Do I simply add a route that maps the ajax  request to a particular controller method, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you are asking a ajax call to fetch data or information you pass the url to that page. But in case of MVC the url becomes controller/function_name. So in url of the ajax call it should be controller/function_name. And since this kind of request is handled by MVC you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Could you give an example of an Ajax function calling a URL of the form "controller/function_name"

Answer (score 0):

They use the same point of entry and flow.
Ajax or not, it's just an request needed of routing.